Two phase pre-training Qwen 2.5?
I have read the Qwen 2.5 Technical Report and other papers, but I am still curious about how they train models in two phases, with each phase using a different context length.
For example, Qwen 2.5 begins with an initial phase using a 4,096-token context length, followed by an extension phase for longer sequences. In the final pre-training stage, the context length is extended from 4,096 to 32,768 tokens.
How do they utilize the pre-trained weights from the first phase in the second phase?
